# Magento 2 php script consuming over 15gb

Tags: php, magento

I have a reasonably new/empty (only added the novetty template to it) magento 2 install and I'm trying to construct a sandbox of it in a vagrant image. I transferred the directory structure and dumped the database, modified the 'core' settings table to reflect the new uri of the sandbox and I'm now trying to run the bin/magento script to do a cache:flush

But when it runs, it quickly consumes over 15gb on the php process before crashing the virtual box.  Any ideas what would be causing this.